# divisibility by 21

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's a simple problem but I am stuck.
The multiple of 21 between 700 and 950 are 714, 735, 756, 777, 798, 819, 840,861,882,903,924,945.
So, there are 12 multiples of 21 between 700 and 950 but 21 *12=252.
So 12 multiples of 21 should take an interval of 252 , and there are only  250 numbers between 700 and 950, So there should be only 11 multiples .
Where am i making a wrong argument ?
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: What on earth is this? You have made literally no effort whatsoever, not even to capitalize the first letter of each sentence. Shame on you.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange, where we're happy to try to help you understand mathematics. A little effort on your part -- like careful writing, and use of capitalization, makes our lives a little easier, which is a nice thing to do when you're asking someone a favor. More important, some effort shown on your part helps us believe we're not just doing your homework for you. Both of these will lead you, I hope, to better questions in the future, and possibly better answers as well.

Comment: The first one ($714$) only "uses up" one of those $250$ numbers (actually it's $251$ or $249$ numbers, depending on what you mean by "between"). Subsequent multiples each "use up" $21$ of the numbers.

Comment: That's the old problem of elementary school: $n$ points on a line determine $n-1$ intervals.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at multiples of $3$ between $2$ and $13$. There are $3, 6, 9, 12$, which is four of them. But $4 \times 3 = 12$, and between $2$ and $13$ is only $11$ numbers.

The problem is that the number $4 \times 3$ doesn't represent the length of the interval containing the four multiples. There are only *three* gaps of length $3$, plus one more for the last number. That's a length of *ten*, which fits easily inside the $11$ spaces you've got.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong when you claim that “$21\times12=252$, so $12$ multiples of $21$ should take an interval of $252$”. The numbers $12$ and and $24$ are two consecutive multiples of $12$, but they take an interval of $13$ numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider, for example, the setof multiples of $15$ between $14$ and $94$ you obtain that there are only $6$ numbers but if you compute $6\cdot15=90$ that is different from $94-14$. You don't have to consider the first of this multiples. In this case, in fact, your method works: $94-14\geq(6-1)\cdot15.$

Comment: That's not right. There are $12$ multiples of $21$ between $713$ and $946$, but the nearest integert to $\frac{946-713}{21}$ is $11$, not $12$.

Comment: I downvoted your post because it was wrong. And it's still wrong: there are $10$ multiples of $21$ between $715$ and $944$, but $\left \lceil \frac{944-715}{21}\right \rceil=11$, not $10$.

Comment: Your formula is not much use if it doesn't work for all inputs!

Comment: Change completely answer.

Answer (score 0):

$21\times12$=252 , so it seems that we need 2 more numbers but when we observe that the the first multiple of 21 in this interval is 714 , we have a surplus of 7 numbers , leaving a net of 7-2=5 numbers extra(from 945 to 950) after 12 multiples.

Thanks to everyone for helping me out.